# Redirection using .regex & htaccess to new URL with added query string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

Trying to redirect old website blog archives using regex and .htaccess to be found under a new site's main archives using a query string including a category filter.

I am trying to make the following redirection work

```
RewriteRule ^blog/2012/04 http://example.com/2012/04?cat=306,10,11 [R=301,L]
```

How can I use regex and .htaccess recognize the `?` in the target URL query string?

Answer (score 0):

The `?` is a special character in regular expressions. It is a quantifier and makes the previous character "optional" means it can be there or not ==> match 0 or 1 time.

So, if you want to match it literally in a string, you have to escape it using a backslash:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/2012/04 http://example\.com/2012/04\?cat=306,10,11 [R=301,L]
```

btw. same for a dot `.`. It is a special character that would match any character, so escape it if it should match a dot.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule consists of 3 parts speparatet by a space

```
the regex: ^blog/2012/04

the target: http://example\.com/2012/04\?cat=306,10,11

flags: [R=301,L]
```

there is no regex applied to the target!

If you want to carry the the query String from the source url to the target url, you can do the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^blog/2012/04$ http://example.com/2012/04?%1 [R=301,L]
```